# Damaged Gore-tex boots

Tags: gear, boots, gore-tex

I bought Aku Slope boots with Gore-tex at a good price and as it turned out they have punctures in one place, which are probably minimal when I check them inside the shoe. I do not want to use the needle to see if they are completely pierced, because I can damage them even more. I tried with a toothpick, and it fits in biggest hole.

Second thing, I'm wondering how to check if they are factory impregnated? Maybe I would have been immersed in water for a moment and saw if they were getting wet right away, but I do not want them to get discolored because then I will not return them.

I would like to point out that I do not care about ultra water resistance, but I do not want them to get wet right away.

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

Thank you

Comment: Hey snowboi, welcome to The Great Outdoors! As it stands, it is unclear to me what exactly you are asking - do you want to know how the punctures will affect the water resistance of your shoes, or if/how you can fix them, or something else? Also, please add pictures as pictures, not as links. Finally, feel free to check out our [tour](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/tour)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long is Gore-Tex lining in boots effective?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16248/how-long-is-gore-tex-lining-in-boots-effective)

Comment: Flagged as a possible duplicate.  The related post has lots of info about gore-tex boot life.The boots in the picture look new, I am guessing they are factory seconds and sold as is, so the current condition is to be expected.  If not factory seconds, you should return them for replacement.

Comment: Welcome from me too snowboi! Would you take a look at the suggested possible duplicate and see if the answers have what you need to know? If not, would you please [edit] your question to add why yours is different? Even if it's a duplicate, it's a good question and you haven't done anything wrong. We just like to keep the same type of information in the same place! [This page](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) in our [help] explains duplicates. We definitely want to help you!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a misplaced stitch line that could well indicate that there are other manufacturing defects as well.

I'm posting this about 10 days too late, but this pair of boots should go back to the manufacturer/outlet and returned as defective.  I sure wouldn't fully trust that toe-cap not to detach under load.

However, if this defect was known and the declared reason for the "good price" you got, then you may have to accept whatever the consequences are, even if you waterproof those stitch holes.